# Can u develop student portal using wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to create a WordPress website student portal.
Every student will have a unique id which they will login and logout
in website. Also include student dashboard.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The direct answer to that is a YES.
There are alot of plugins tailored to that specifically.
Nevertheless, wordpress, just like most other CMSs in general has alot of limitation when it comes to customizing things to exactly how you want it.
Alteernatively, consider strapi, a headless CMS, it gives you a fast means of creating API and then you can choose any frontend library of your choice to go with.